# Adding Image Button To My MainActivity.java

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imagebutton

In my new project i just added a image button with id imagebutton1.
Should i describe about this in my MainActivity.java,If yes how to?

Comment: can you describe a little more about what all you have done upto now

Comment: I have got the answer, anyway thanks..

Answer (score 0):

ِYou should make a reference to it in you MainActivity's onCreate function like below.

`ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);`

Comment: you can also try this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html